# Read a text file and print pre-defined html when specific keywords are found

Tags: php, html, parsing, regex

How can I code this in a better way, in one file? Output must be more than one (if there is more that one status_update with the given word "online or performancedegradation"), like:

> ```
> #online
> System is operating at peak performance.
>
> #directonly
> Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.
> ```

```
<?php
$filename = "export_file_system_status_output";   
$status_update = "online";  
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");  
$file = fread($handle,filesize($filename));  
if (preg_match('#' . $status_update . '#', $file, $match)) {  
echo "<div id=badge_subpage_system>
                                        <h5>#online</h5>
                                        <p>System is operating at peak performance.</p>
                                    </div>";
}  
?>

<?php
$filename = "export_file_system_status_output";   
$status_update = "performancedegradation";  
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");  
$file = fread($handle,filesize($filename));  
if (preg_match('#' . $status_update . '#', $file, $match)) {  
echo "<div id=badge_subpage_system>
                                        <h5>#performancedegradation</h5>
                                        <p>Performance is slower than normal.</p>
                                    </div>";
}
?>
                                    
<?php
$filename = "export_file_system_status_output";   
$status_update = "directonly";  
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");  
$file = fread($handle,filesize($filename));  
if (preg_match('#' . $status_update . '#', $file, $match)) {  
echo "<div id=badge_subpage_system>
                                        <h5>#directonly</h5>
                                        <p>Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.</p>
                                     </div>";
}
?>
```

It must sort by first status_update found:

1. **online**

   ```
   #online

   System is operating at peak performance.
   ```
2. then **performancedegradation**

   ```
   #directonly

   Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.
   ```

Comment: use conditions, if there are more then use a switch case. File name ends with type of file. Your code is not having full file name

Comment: It must sort by first status_update found: Online => then #online
System is operating at peak performance.

performancedegradation => #directonly
Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint. Try using a foreach loop:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

You can store all your files and associated information in an associative array, such as:

```
$files = array(
  0 => array(
    'filename' => "export_file_system_status_output";   
    'status_update' => "online";
  ),
  1 => array(
    'filename' => "another_file";   
    'status_update' => "offline";
  )
);
```

You should really try this on your own :) If you don't get it, I'll give you a more complete answer :)

On a side note, your HTML is not valid. Use classes instead of ids when possible, and use quotes:

```
<div class="badge_subpage_system">
  <h5>#performancedegradation</h5>
  <p>Performance is slower than normal.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

EDIT:

Here's what your final code will look like, with the array I posted above:

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
  $handle = fopen($file['filename'], "r");
  $file = fread($handle,filesize($file['filename']));
  if (preg_match('#' . $file['status_update'] . '#', $file, $match))
  {
    echo '<div id="badge_subpage_system"><h5>#performancedegradation</h5><p>Performance is slower than normal.</p></div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: like this:
    $arr = array("0", "1", "2");
    reset($arr);
    while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
    }

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
    }

Comment: The second line seems right, yes :) The first line is just messy :s Always think about the fact that if others read your code, they should be able to understand easily what your code does.

Comment: Can't get it fixed :( Can you help me on this one?

Comment: Sorry for being so late :s anyway, in case you still need help, I've updated my answer aboce :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Write D.R.Y. code.  Do not ask php to open the same unchanged file 3 times, just open it once.
2. Be precise about where in your text you expect to find your specified keywords.
3. Use a lookup to generate the regex and to quickly determine the desired text to present for each occurrence.
4. HTML markup must have unique `id` attributes in the document.  Since your output is repeating, you should use a `class` instead of `id`.  Your attribute values should be quoted as well.
5. Though I typically advise against using single-use variables, in this case it serves to separate and describe specific pieces of data / operations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CJUV6))

```
$lookup = [
    '#online' => 'System is operating at peak performance.',
    '#performancedegradation' => 'Performance is slower than normal.',
    '#directonly' => 'Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.'
];
$regex = '/^(?:' . implode('|', array_keys($lookup)) . ')(?=\s)/m';

$contents = file_get_contents("export_file_system_status_output.txt");
$matches = preg_match_all($regex, $contents, $m) ? $m[0] : [];
foreach ($matches as $keyword) {
    printf(
        '<div class="badge_subpage_system"><h5>%s</h5><p>%s</p></div>',
        $keyword,
        $lookup[$keyword]
   );
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="badge_subpage_system"><h5>#online</h5><p>System is operating at peak performance.</p></div>
<div class="badge_subpage_system"><h5>#directonly</h5><p>Traffic is bypassing Smart CDN system, and going directly to websites.</p></div>
```